# Сделать маппинг иерархии на плоскую Dto

Tags: c#, automapper

Допустим, у меня есть класс в который вложена коллекция объектов другого класса.

Наружу я хочу отправлять плоскую модель.

Скажем было так:

```
var class1=new Class1("Бла Бла Бла", new List<Class2>(){new Class2("Бла2"),new Class2("Бла3")})
```

А в итоге хочу получить вот такой результат:

```
var dtoClassList=new List<DtoClass>(){new DtoClass("Бла Бла Бла","Бла2"),new DtoClass("Бла Бла Бла","Бла3")}
```

Можно ли как-нибудь добиться такого через AutoMapper?

Пока пришел к такому способу:

Делаю настройку отображения class1 на dtoClassList
Делаю настройку отображения class2 на dtoClassList

Далее через SelectMany создаю плоскую коллекцию из class1.
Далее в цикле foreach создаю DtoClass и вызываю на этот объект

```
_mapper.Map(class1, dtoClass );
_mapper.Map(Class2, dtoClass );
```

и добавляю в результирующую коллекцию.

Может быть можно проще?

Comment: Допустим в классе есть два класса и у них есть поле ID. Как вы собираетесь разруливать одинаковые имена? Приписывать имена классов?

Comment: @AK Скажем... я к этому буду готов и в Dto для каждого такого Id создам уникальное поле по типу ClassNameId.

Answer (score 3):

Возможно вам подойдет использование кастомного `TypeConverter`:

```cs
public record Class1(string name, List<Class2> list);
public record Class2(string name);
public record Dto(string class1Name, string class2Name);

public class FlatConverter : ITypeConverter<Class1, List<Dto>>
{
    public List<Dto> Convert(Class1 source, List<Dto> destination, ResolutionContext context)
        => source.list
            .Select(class2 => new Dto(source.name, class2.name))
            .ToList();
}

// ...
cfg.CreateMap<Class1, List<Dto>>().ConvertUsing<FlatConverter>();

// данные из вашего примера
var class1 = new Class1(
    "Бла Бла Бла",
    new List<Class2>()
    {
        new Class2("Бла2"),
        new Class2("Бла3")
    });

var dto = mapper.Map<List<Dto>>(class1);
```

`dto` будет содержать список классов, где одно поле взято из родительского класса, второе из дочернего.

Comment: Получается, что я тут должен буду сам ручками перемапить все?

Comment: @iluxa1810 в `TypeConverter` можно использовать `Map` (через `context`), но нужно будет ещё зарегистрировать маппинг Class2->Dto, но я не вижу проблемы в ручном маппинге, т.к. это все равно часть вашей маппинг конфигурации